# How to add String from one array to another

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I can't seem to append a string from arrayOne into arrayTwo. It's a very simple problem and I have Googled around and have tried different examples that I found below. Does anyone see the obvious issue here?

```
[_arrayTwo addObject:arrayOne[i]]; // int i
[_arrayTwo addObject:[arrayOne objectAtIndex:i]]; // int i
[_arrayTwo addObject:@"Test"]; // I can't even add a literal string

NSString *tempString = [arrayOne objectAtIndex:i];
[arrayTwo addObject:tempString];
```

**NSLog Output:**

```
NSLog(@"%@", _imageArray); // Result is "(null)"
```

**Additional Notes:**

1. arrayOne is healthy (contains NSString values)
2. Both arrays are NSMutableArray (declared as properties in the .h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe _imageArray is nil

Try adding in

```
_imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In your init method call.